# Sending email by Spring via Google ()

Tags: java, spring, gmail

The code below works well

But, my question is how can set the 'javaMailProperties' programaticaly ?
Because I would like to set ssl/tsl from the code. I could not access these properties, I dont know why, thanks for the solution and explanation.

```
SimpleMailMessage message=(SimpleMailMessage)SpringUtil.getContext().
getBean("templateMessage");

JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = (JavaMailSenderImpl)SpringUtil.getContext()
.getBean("mailSender"); 

mailSender.send(message);

--applicationcontext.xml--

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
   <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
   <property name="port" value="587"/>
   <property name="username" value="your gmail address"/>
   <property name="password" value="your password"/>        

   <property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>

 </bean>

<bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" >
<property name="from" value="from@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="to" value="to@gmail.com"/>              
    <property name="subject" value="subject"/>
    <property name="text" value="hello"/>               
 </bean>
```

(I dont want to use javax.mail approach, it was asked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
mailSender.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Same for other properties that you want to set programatically.

*EDIT:*

I checked the source code for the `JavaMailSenderImpl` class:

```
/**
 * Allow Map access to the JavaMail properties of this sender,
 * with the option to add or override specific entries.
 * <p>Useful for specifying entries directly, for example via
 * "javaMailProperties[mail.smtp.auth]".
 */
public Properties getJavaMailProperties() {
    return this.javaMailProperties;
}
```

As you can see, the getJavaMailProperties is a public method and should be available to you. My Spring framework version is 3.0.5.

Comment: We came across the some problem, there is no getJavaMailProperties(), but setJavaMailProperties exits :) Thanks for the effort and your time

Comment: @cscsaba I added pertinent source code for the `JamaMailSenderImpl` class. `getJavaMailProperties()` is a public method and should be available to you.

Comment: Marcelo: wait a minute, check this url http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/springframework, I know Spring 3 has been come out, the maven repo has no newer version, thats why i made this test case with version Springframework 2.0

Comment: @cscsaba You should actually be looking at this link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework. Latest version is 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Comment: I managed to get Spring 3 and your are right there getJavaMailProperties, sorry for this confusion

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks again, really, I was blind

Answer (score 0):

A quick google not verified. 
Call setProperty(String key, String value) on the mailSender.getJavaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth",true)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: I can say the same than to Marcelo (see above) We came across the some problem, there is no getJavaMailProperties(), but setJavaMailProperties exits :) Thanks for help